# is this iterator operation undefined in c++

Tags: c++, gcc

```
it++ = nodes.insert(it, new_node);
```

where nodes is a std::vector and "it" is iterator type.

I got different behavior on gcc-7.3.0 & gcc-5.4.0.
Just wondering whether this is a undefined behavior?

On gcc-7.3.0, it's the same as:

```
it = nodes.insert(it, new_node);
it++
```

On gcc-5.4.0, it's the same as:

```
it = nodes.insert(it, new_node);
it = std::advance(it,2);
```

Comment: Is `it` an iterator into `nodes`?  What behavior do you get with the two compiler versions?

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can't say if it is or isn't.  It is something that is allowed and used though.

Comment: sorry that I forgot to add ++ operator after it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `it` is a valid iterator into `nodes`, then this seems valid. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert for details.

If `it` is *not* a valid iterator, then it is Undefined Behaviour.